# What happens if multiple directives are on a single element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular JS, I need to know how to make specific directive to be execute first where we have 2 or more directives on same element.
example directives directiveone directivetwo direvtivethree on div tag

```
<div>
    <div directiveone directivetwo direvtivethree></div>
</div>
```

but i need to load directivetwo first followed by direvtivethree then direvtiveone.

Please give your suggestions...

Comment: I have only few knowledge in angular js but I think it will be read from top to bottom and left to right so the first declared directive will be run.

Comment: thanks for reply, but how to load specific directive first..?? Is there any property for it..??

Answer (score 2):

You should use directive `priority` in-order to determine which directives should compile first.

```
var myModule = angular.module(...); 
myModule.directive('directiveName', function (injectables) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div></div>',
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    replace: false,
    priority: 0,
    transclude: false,
    ...
```

This option tells angular to sort directives by priority so a directive having higher priority will be compiled/linked before others.

Answer (score 1):

Add **priority** attribute:

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
    return {
        priority: *numeric value*,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function() {

        }
    }
}
```

Execution order is by highest priority number.
If not specified, priority is 0 and directives are executed alphabetically.